# How to convert dataframe rows to variables in R

Tags: r

If I have a 2 column, 4 row data frame such as:

```
structure(list(var = c("url.loc", "radius", "jt", "post.age"), 
value = c("london", "25", "fulltime", "7")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(var = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x60000323fee0>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

... how would I go about converting this to 4 variables so the result would be the same as:

```
url.loc <- "london"
radius <- "25"
jt <- "fulltime"
post.age <- "7"
```

I can think of using `assign` and a loop, but I'm thinking there's a more elegant way, perhaps using NSE.

thanks

Comment: You should think carefully about *why* you want to do this: in general this is a sign that you’re approaching the problem from a wrong angle. This kind of operation is rarely (if ever) necessary or helpful.

Comment: I'm reading in from a CSV and setting variables to be used in a container on Google Cloud.  I need the variables to be in a specific YAML file by changing only object - the CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may create a named `list` and use `list2env`

```
library(tibble)
list2env(as.list(deframe(df1)), .GlobalEnv)
```

-checking

```
> url.loc
[1] "london"
> radius
[1] "25"
```

---

A compact option is with `%=%` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
df1$var %=% df1$value
```

-checking

```
> url.loc
[1] "london"
> radius
[1] "25"
```